# Is 'const T*' a cv-unqualified type?

Tags: c++, types, qualifiers

In C++ standard there is much wording including the term "cv-qualified" and "cv-unqualified". It's already known that a cv-qualified type is a type contains a set of cv-qualifiers: one of {`"const"`}, {`"volatile"`}, {`"const, volatile"`}, {`" "`}.

But I get confused when the type returned by `std::remove_cv_t<const T*>` is actually `const T*` not `T*`. Why?

Consider this declaration `const int *volatile ptr{}`, if we assume the type of `ptr` is `cv T`; what `T` is? what `cv` is?

Another examples,

```
const int&& r1 = 0; 
const int* &&r2 = 0;
const int *const &r3 = 0;
```

- If the type of `r1` is `cv1 T1`; what `T1` is? what `cv1` is?
- If the type of `r2` is `cv2 T2`; what `T2` is? what `cv2` is?
- If the type of `r3` is `cv3 T3`; what `T3` is? what `cv3` is?

Comment: `const T*` is the cv-unqualified form of `const T* const volatile`.  It's a pointer type, and the pointer is neither const nor volatile.

Comment: [basic.type.qualifier]/6: "_In this document, the notation cv (or cv1, cv2, etc.), used in the description of types, represents an arbitrary
set of cv-qualifiers, i.e., one of {const}, {volatile}, {const, volatile}, or the empty set. **For a type cv T,
the top-level cv-qualifiers of that type are those denoted by cv**_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I get confused when the type returned by `std::remove_cv_t<const T*>` is actually `const T*` not `T*`. Why?

`const` on the left is kind of a lie.  If you use right hand const it makes a lot more sense.  `const T *` can be rewritten as `T const *` and when read from right to left is "non-const pointer to a `const T`", so it is not cv-qualified.  `T * const` on the other hand is `const` pointer to `T`, so it is cv-qualified.

> Consider this declaration `const int *volatile ptr{}`, if we assume the type of `ptr` is `cv T`; what `T` is? what `cv` is?

With `const int *volatile ptr` you have a `volatile` pointer to a `const int`, so `T` is `int const *` and cv-qualification of `T` is `volatile`.

In your last example, none of the references are cv-qualified as that would require `const` to be on the right hand side of the reference (i.e.: `int & const`).  We are not actually allowed to do that though so reference are never cv-qualified.

Comment: So for example `T3` is `const int *const` and `cv3` is empty set?

Comment: @John Yes.  You would need `const int *const & const r3` for `cv3` to be `const` be we are not allowed to do that.